# Fetch the row which has the second max value in a column from a table postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, max, greatest-n-per-group

my table is

```
 emp_id | emp_name |  emp_doj   |    emp_desg     |  pay   | manager_id
--------+----------+------------+-----------------+--------+------------
      3 | John     | 2008-12-20 | MTS             |  93750 |          3
      5 | manoj    | 2014-08-10 | Project Trainee | 200000 |          3
      6 | kumar    | 2014-09-12 | Project Trainee |  15000 |          3
      2 | Sree     | 2014-09-12 | ZU              | 150000 |          3
```

I want to get the complete row from this table which row has second highest pay. That is, I want to get the details of sree here....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select max(pay) from table_name where pay NOT IN(select max(pay) from table_name) LIMIT 0,1
```

this will helpful for you.

Comment: Actually I want to get the whole row...getting errors when I do that

Comment: Should specify like select emp_id, emp_name,emp_doj,emp_desg,emp_manager_id,max(pay) as pay from table_name where pay NOT IN(select max(pay) from table_name)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done using a window function:

```
select emp_id, emp_name, emp_doj, emp_desg, pay, manager_id
from (
  select emp_id, emp_name, emp_doj, emp_desg, pay, manager_id,
         dense_rank() over (order by pay desc) as rnk
  from employee
) t
where rnk = 2;
```

If two employees have the same pay, both will be returned. If you only want one of them returned, use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`